# module 'snappy' has no attribute 'decompress'

Tags: python, python-3.x, kafka-consumer-api, snappy

I'm tring to use kafka-python. It request to install Snappy. So I install it by

1. pip install snappy
2. pip install python_snappy-0.5.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl 
   In both ways Snappy install successfully.

But in both time when i'm trying to run python code where i import 'kafka', i got an error.

Error:

> AttributeError: module 'snappy' has no attribute 'decompress'

When I run,

```
import snappy
help(snappy)
```

Result is:

```
Help on package snappy:

NAME
    snappy

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    __main__
    _snappy
    hadoop_snappy
    snappy
    snappy_cffi
    snappy_cffi_builder
    snappy_formats

FILE
    (built-in)
```

I'm using conda in Windows environment (Win 10).

How can i overcome this problem?

Comment: May this help you. https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/issues/751

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I believe you've installed [SnapPy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/snappy) a package for geometry. You should install `pip install python-snappy` instead of `pip install snappy`. The snappy package you're looking for is here [Python-snappy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-snappy)

Comment: Don't forget to `apt install libsnappy-dev` BEFORE installing pip package on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: @Riki137 genius! Exactly what happened to me. `libsnappy-dev` was installed, and so was `snappy` in `pip`. But they it didn't work until I reinstalled `snappy`